# Load more mysql results with button

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I'm making an image sharing website where users can sign up and upload their own pictures or ones they have found on the internet. The file path gets uploaded to a MySQL database. Then I use a MySQL query to pull all of the image paths out and using a while loop I put the images onto the page. As more images get uploaded, the longer it will take for the page to load. I want to add a load more button after 5 images that when pressed loads another 5 images. I can't seem to find a tutorial for this anywhere.

The table is called images and the column name is path.

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `images` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $path = $row['path'];
?>
    <img src="<?php echo $path; ?>" alt="" />
<?php
}
?>
```

This is the come I'm using to get the file path. This is not what I have a problem with. The problem is, there is too many images on the page and it makes the loading speed really slow. So this is why I want to load 5 at a time. If you think it will be better to load while the user is scrolling, please help me know how to do that too.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is pagination. I started to tell you to google it but after I did myself I see there's so much bad advice out that it's not worth it.

First off you want to be using the more modern methods of connecting to a mysql database. The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated in PHP and they are considered a security risk.  I prefer [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) which gives you a nice consistant interface to many different databases. Another option is [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) which is a bit easier if you're used to the `mysql_*` functions

From there it's a matter of just limiting the query and then letting your script know which group of values to return. This is how I do it (note I didn't test this so there are probably bugs! You'll also need to decide how to handle the output and the errors)

```
// Database connection stuff goes here

$start = $_GET['start'];
$per_page = 10; // or config value of your choice

// first find out how many you have
try {
    $res = $dbh->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `images`" );
    $res->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    // do something with errors!
}

list($count) = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

$end = $start + $per_page;
if( $count < $end ) {
    $end = $count;
}

// next and previous values. Just create links and these 
// become the "start" parameter
$next = $end + 1;
$prev = $start - $per_page;
if( $prev < 0 ) {
    $prev = 0
}


// now get the results
try {
    $res = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `images` 
        ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT $start, $end");
    $res->execute();

    while( $image = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        // store or output the results
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    // do something with errors!
}
```

For doing it automatically when scrolling you can use jQuery to check a scroll event and then call your backend code to load more results automatically (by setting the $prev and $next values into the calls)

Comment: I get errors with the code. Undefined variables and functions

Comment: This example uses PDO which you would have to setup. it won't work out of the box.

Comment: How would I set PDO up? I'm slightly new to PHP and I don't recognize much code out of the box.

Comment: Sorry. I thought I linked it in my original post. Here is the official documentation: http://php.net/PDO and here's here's a great tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Comment: Yes you did. Sorry. I seen it but it was too late to edit my comment. Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only 5 use [Select Top 5](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp) and if you want to upload new files while they scroll you could use Ajax. Hope you will find the way to do it and share it.